# Refresh linear layout with new elements onactivityresult

Tags: android

I am creating a jsonobject and sending it to my previous activity, that activity parses it and displays child linearlayouts containing image and text view combinations. These child linearlayouts are added in a parent linearlayout using add view.

The jsonobject changes according to user inputs, but unfortunately the linearlayout is not refreshing when I am giving it a new jsonobject onactivityresult method, instead the linearlayout is preserving it's previous state containing the child views.

Is there a way to make sure the linearlayout refreshes with the new object details evertime the onactivityresult is called?

Comment: without code it is difficult to debug ! but could you try with calling invalidateLayout()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you're removing the old data before adding some fresh content. If you're already doing this, try using invalidate().

Android docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Comment: How do we remove old data before adding new data? I am only using addview functions and doing invalidate, but it won't work.

Comment: You can use the removeAllViews method to do this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()

Answer (score 0):

1. In the same Activity you can use AsyncTask and after data is loaded then call say update_data_function(){used to update values} in onPostExecute function.

   ```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( Void... voids ) {
   //download data
   return null;
    }
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    update_data_function(result);
     }
    }.execute();
   ```
2. You can use custom Interface in 2nd activity that gets loaded data but implement this interface in your main activity where you want to show data and pass data to update_data_function() in main activity.

   ```
      public class SecondActivity{

      public interface OnDataPass {
      public void onDataPass(String data);
      }

    public class FirstActivity{
     //implement onDataPass here to get data and call update_data_function()}
   ```

Comment: Not sure how this will make the views to be refreshed.